# How to know if returning an l-value when using `FALLBACK`?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku, lvalue

How can I know if I actually need to return an l-value when using `FALLBACK`?

I'm using `return-rw` but I'd like to only use `return` where possible.  I want to track if I've actually modified `%!attrs` or have only just read the value when `FALLBACK` was called.

Or (alternate plan B) can I attach a callback or something similar to my `%!attrs` to monitor for changes?

```
class Foo {
  has %.attrs;
  submethod BUILD { %!attrs{'bar'} = 'bar' }

#  multi method FALLBACK(Str:D $name, *@rest) {
#    say 'read-only';
#    return %!attrs{$name} if %!attrs«$name»:exists;
#  }

  multi method FALLBACK(Str:D $name, *@rest) {
    say 'read-write';
    return-rw %!attrs{$name} if %!attrs«$name»:exists;
  }
}

my $foo = Foo.new;
say $foo.bar;

$foo.bar = 'baz';
say $foo.bar;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feels a bit like a X-Y question, so let's simplify the example, and see if that answers helps in your decisions.

First of all: if you return the "value" of a non-existing key in a hash, you are in fact returning a container that will auto-vivify the key in the hash when assigned to:

```
my %hash;
sub get($key) { return-rw %hash{$key} }
get("foo") = 42;
dd %hash;   # Hash %hash = {:foo(42)}
```

Please note that you need to use `return-rw` here to ensure the actual container is returned, rather than just the value in the container.  Alternately, you can use the `is raw` trait, which allows you to just set the last value:

```
my %hash;
sub get($key) is raw { %hash{$key} }
get("foo") = 42;
dd %hash;   # Hash %hash = {:foo(42)}
```

Note that you should *not* use `return` in that case, as that will still de-containerize again.

To get back to your question:

> I want to track if I've actually modified `%!attrs` or have only just read the value when `FALLBACK` was called.

```
class Foo {
    has %!attrs;
    has %!unexpected;

    method TWEAK() { %!attrs<bar> = 'bar' }

    method FALLBACK(Str:D $name, *@rest) is raw {
        if %!attrs{$name}:exists {
            %!attrs{$name}
        }
        else {
            %!unexpected{$name}++;
            Any
        }
    }
}
```

This would either return the container found in the hash, or record the access to the unknown key and return an immutable `Any`.

Regarding plan B, recording changes: for that you could use a [Proxy](https://docs.raku.org/type/Proxy) object for that.

Hope this helps in your quest.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

Liz's answer is full of useful info and you've accepted it but I thought the following might still be of interest.

> How to know if returning an l-value ... ?

Let's start by ignoring the `FALLBACK` clause.

You would have to test the value. To deal with `Scalar`s, you must test the [`.VAR`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop#index-entry-syntax_VAR-VAR) of the value. (For non-`Scalar` values the `.VAR` acts like a "no op".) I *think* (but don't quote me) that `Scalar|Array|Hash` covers all the *l-value* super-types:

```
my \value       = 42;  # Int is an l-value is False
my \l-value-one = $;   # Scalar is an l-value is True
my \l-value-too = @;   # Array is an l-value is True

say "{.VAR.^name} is an l-value is {.VAR ~~ Scalar|Array|Hash}"
  for value, l-value-one, l-value-too
```

> How to know if returning an l-value *when using `FALLBACK`*?

Adding "when using `FALLBACK`" makes no difference to the answer.

> How can I know if I actually *need* to return an *l-value* ... ?

Again, let's start by ignoring the `FALLBACK` clause.

This is a completely different question than "How to know if returning an l-value ... ?". I think it's the core of your question.

Afaik, the answer is, you need to anticipate how the returned value will be used. If there's *any* chance it'll be used as an *l-value*, and you want that usage to work, then you need to return an *l-value*. The language/compiler can't (or at least doesn't) help you make that decision.

Consider some related scenarios:

```
my $baz := foo.bar;
... (100s of lines of code) ...
$baz = 42;
```

Unless the first line returns an *l-value*, the second line will fail.

But the situation is actually much more immediate than that:

```
routine-foo = 42;
```

`routine-foo` is evaluated first, in its entirety, *before the `lhs = rhs` expression is evaluated*.

Unless the compiler's resolution of the `routine-foo` call somehow incorporated the fact that the very next thing to happen would be that the `lhs` will be assigned to, then there would be no way for a singly or multiply dispatched `routine-foo` to know whether it can safely return an *r-value* or must return an *l-value*.

And the compiler's resolution does *not* incorporate that. Thus, for example:

```
multi term:<bar> is rw { ... }
multi term:<bar>       { ... }
bar = 99; # Ambiguous call to 'term:<bar>(...)'
```

I can *imagine* this one day (N years from now) being solved by a combination of allowing `=` to be an overloadable operator, robust macros that allow overloading of `=` being available, and routine resolution being modified so the above ambiguous call could do something equivalent to resolving to the `is rw` multi. But I doubt it will *actually* come to pass even with N=10. Perhaps there is another way but I can't think of one at the moment.

> How can I know if I actually need to return an *l-value* *when using `FALLBACK`*?

Again, adding "when using `FALLBACK`" makes no difference to the answer.

> I want to track if I've actually modified `%!attrs` or have only just read the value when `FALLBACK` was called.

When `FALLBACK` is called it doesn't know what context it's being called in -- *r-value* or *l-value*. Any modification comes after it has already returned.

In other words, whatever solution you come up with will being nothing to do per se with `FALLBACK` (even if you have to use it to implement some other aspect of whatever it is you're trying to do).

(Even if it were, I suspect trying to solve it via `FALLBACK` itself would just make matters *worse*. One can imagine writing two `FALLBACK` multis, one with an `is rw` trait, but, as explained above, my imagination doesn't stretch to that making any difference any time soon, if ever, and could only happen if the above imaginary things happened (the macros etc.) *and* the compiler was *also* modified to pay attention to the two `FALLBACK` multi variants, and I'm not at all meaning to suggest that that even makes sense.)

## Plan B

> Or (alternate plan B) can I attach a callback or something similar to my `%!attrs` to monitor for changes?

As Lizmat notes, that's the realm of `Proxy`s. And thus your next SO question... :)

Comment: Yes, I got excited and accepted the above answer before finding out Proxy would not work on a hash.  I've been experimenting to see if the meta-programming stuff I can do in Ruby are possible in Perl 6.  It's no problem if some of it's not there yet, I can wait.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`